# Add data to list from pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list

Python newborn here, I want to extract values from data-frame into a list, but I get extra information that I don't need. Is there a better way to do this:

```
rating1 = []
rating2 = []
for value in person1["Movie"]:
    for value2 in person2["Movie"]:
        if value == value2:
            rating1.append(person1[person1["Movie"] == value]["Rating"])
            rating2.append(person2[person2["Movie"] == value2]["Rating"])
```

When I print rating1 I get this:

```
print(rating1)
[0    2.5
Name: Rating, dtype: float64, 1    3.5
Name: Rating, dtype: float64, 2    2.5
Name: Rating, dtype: float64, 5    3.0
Name: Rating, dtype: float64, 22    3.5
Name: Rating, dtype: float64, 23    3.0
Name: Rating, dtype: float64]
```

My goal is only to extract the ratings without index and other info to use for calculating Manhattan and Euclidean distance. 
Something like this:

```
[2.5, 3.5, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 3.0]
```

Comment: This will help you - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html

Comment: person1[person1["Movie"] == value]["Rating"] is actually a pd.Series object. So instead of appending the actual (float) values to the list you are appending Series Objects. To get the values out of these object, use the .values attribute: person1[person1["Movie"] == value]["Rating"].values

Comment: Please share a snapshot of your dataset say `person1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer for my problem, here it is for future reference.
Was using append method, changed this to extend method and the result is exactly what I want.

```
rating1 = []
rating2 = []
for value in person1["Movie"]:
    for value2 in person2["Movie"]:
        if value == value2:
            rating1.extend(person1[person1["Movie"] == value]["Rating"])
            rating2.extend(person2[person2["Movie"] == value2]["Rating"])

print(rating1)
>>>[2.5, 3.5, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 3.0]
```

This way I can call the Euclidean and Manhattan methods like this:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
r1 = np.array(rating1)
r2 = np.array(rating2)

euclidean = distance.euclidean(r1, r2)
manhattan = distance.cityblock(r1, r2)
```